# Is there a way to evaluate group values in dict and append them to several lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to iterate over every pair of dictionary.keys() and get every two dictionary.values() matching and append them to a new list every loop with specific order. 
So the dictionary I get after sorting array is,

```
dictionary =

{0.0: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794], 

2.30078: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794], 

4.60156: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794], 

6.90234: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794],

9.20313: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794], 

11.5039: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794], 

13.8047: [0.0, 2.27991, 4.55981, 6.83972, 9.11963, 11.3995, 13.6794]}
```

and the list`s I would like to get are

```
list_%is = 

[0.0,0.0,0.0,2.27991,2.30078,0.0,2.30078,2.27991]

[key1,value1-1,key1,value1-2,key2,value2-1,key2,value2-2]
```

with continuing the iteration the second one would be :

```
[0.0,2.27991,0.0,4.55981,2.30078,2.27991,2.30078,4.55981]
```

and just for clarifying the sequence:

```
[key1,value1-2,key1,value1-3,key2,value2-2,key2,value2-3]
```

so that every starting second key, value will be first output in the n+1 iteration.

I have tried to get them by simple nested for loops but I`m ending with 4-5 for loops with 2-3 sub if statement and wrong output, not to mention the empty iterations and the slow solution time if the dictionary is way bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your tentativeness to continue using for loops and if statements but I believe you can achieve it in just 2 for loops and a couple extra variables.

This is how I solved it,

```
outList = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(dictionary)-1):
  outTemp = []
  for key in dictionary:
    outTemp.extend([key,dictionary[key][i],dictionary[key][i+1]])
  outList.append(outTemp)
print(outList)
```

You can see an example of this working [HERE](https://repl.it/repls/TornBackSoftwareengineer).

Comment: I' m glad for answering mine question so fast and thank you for introducing me to that extend function, It's working nicely here. I just would like to add a matching statement between the two """[key][I]""" values during the iterations.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by matching? Seeing if they are equal? And if so to do what with it.

Comment: Yes, I mean seeing if they are equal. The other thing is that your code is missing for 120 values ( 60 keys and 60 values) , which I don`t see how would be add without a third for loop. The thing is that this dictionary is consisting of x,y coordinates, where every intersection between every two sequential keys(e.g. lists) is forming a square, where every two squares are sharing two common nodes (so (key,value;key,value)*2). So in the end from this input the final output will be 36 lists with 8 values each.That is the big picture problem. Greetings !